# regular expression to check file content type is .doc or not?

Tags: c#, regex

When i use a file upload i use to check file contenttype with regular expressions... For ex

```
private bool IsImage(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        if (file != null && Regex.IsMatch(file.ContentType, "image/\\S+") &&
          file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This returns my file is an image or not... How to check it is a word(.doc/.docx) document or not using c#...

Comment: Why don’t you identify the file type by the file name extension?

Comment: @Gumbo that sounds really good i ve done it before.. Ok i ll try it out..

Comment: filetype checking not advised when you don't have proper file checking. For example if someone uploads a exe, with an extension .doc, and then you parse it. You will need error checking (same as with MIMEtype checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example using Axarydax answer: (so no docx mime check)

```
List<String> wordMimeTypes = new List<String>();
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/msword");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/doc");
wordMimeTypes.Add("appl/text");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/vnd.msword");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/vnd.ms-word");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/winword");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/word");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/x-msw6");
wordMimeTypes.Add("application/x-msword");
//etc...etc...

if (wordMimeTypes.Contains(file.ContentType))
{
    //word document
}
else
{
    //not a word document
}
```

More readable than Regex because regex will become a pain in the ass when trying to make a expression for a dozen of mime types

Comment: why is mine accepted as answer? Axarydax made the answer, I only provided some code to explain my comment to his answer.

Comment: because the copy-paste-able anwser always gets the check mark.

Answer (score 6):

DOC's mimetype is:

- application/msword [official]
- application/doc
- appl/text
- application/vnd.msword
- application/vnd.ms-word
- application/winword
- application/word
- application/x-msw6
- application/x-msword

happy regex'ing

Edit:According to @Dan Diplo, you should also check for .docx's MIMEtypes

Comment: also fo docx - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: All the Word 2007 mime-types can be found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278.aspx  They are quite a mouthful!

Comment: @Axarydax how to give for word file instead of `"image/\\S+"`

Comment: if you read there are many options. Why not just have a vector with these mimetypes in it and then check if the mimetype of the file exists in that list?

Answer (score 1):

if the content-type's are known (see Axarydax answer), why would you want to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [regexblid](http://regexplib.com/) A library with regular expression.

Also good to know, [regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) can be used to validate and test regular expressions.

Comment: Bit useless to post regexblid when there are no regex for documents on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Gumbo is right, it might just be easier to check the file's extension.

```
Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)
```